# You go wherever you go today

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, metapuzzles

<sup>A conclusion to my entries in the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #32: Grid Deduction Hybrids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5998/2071).  This metapuzzle incorporates the three previous puzzles in this series:</sup>

<sup>[Desert Irrigation Project](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52896/desert-irrigation-project)</sup>
<sup>[I am an Island](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53009/i-am-an-island-ysaujdiolkiun)</sup>
<sup>[My God, it's full of stars!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/my-god-its-full-of-stars)</sup>

---

I have received another envelope from my dear friend, this one somewhat larger.  Alas, it also has no return address.

Inside the envelope were these two sheets:

[image: Rules Layout 1]

[image: Rules Layout 2]

Additionally, there were 5 square sheets of vellum:

[image: Vellum 1]

[image: Vellum 2]

[image: Vellum 3]

[image: Vellum 4]

[image: Vellum 5]

And finally there was this one large sheet:

[image: You Go Today]

Wherever he is now, I hope he settles there until someone has a chance to catch up with him.  Now it's just a matter of finding where he is.

Comment: This is more than a mindful, paramesis. We must go space filling together some day.

Comment: How long have you been waiting to post this?!

Comment: @Wen1now I designed the puzzle and main painting about 5 months ago, but never got around to rendering all the other layouts.

Comment: @lauir I'm afraid I don't fill that much space, just a small corner with a drafting board and printer.

Comment: I don’t think any of the others have been solved and two of them haven’t even had any answers posted. Will we need to solve them to solve this?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I tried to design this puzzle such that that was the case, but I would imagine it is still possible to solve independently, but much harder/more tedious.

Comment: Maybe this will help somebody, here is what I found. The rectangles on the first image are flags. First is the flag of japan then USA or malasia or georgia. I can´t find this flag exactly but it seems like it can be thailand or costa rica. The last one is south korea´s flag (I don´t know if this was deliberate or not but the flag is wrong)

Comment: I already posted this at your other puzzles of the series: I really like the artwork/style! Now I just hope all four get solved. Maybe it needs some *joint effort* of the great brains here on site?

Comment: The shapes at the top of the first image seem to be vowels, A E I O U.

Comment: @CanAcar the last one does look like the South Korean flag except missing the red over blue swirl. Though honestly, of they are flags, the last one HAS to be South Korea, its unique in the sense that no other flag in the world looks like that. :)

Comment: Though one side note to @paramesis, if Flag five is South Korea, its a bit off. The Korean flag's three rows of black bars are actually as follows: Top left hand corner is three solid black bars. Bottom left hand corner is a solid bar, followed by a solid bar split in half, followed by anotther solid bar. The top right hand corner is solid bar cut in half, solid bar, solid bar cut in half, and finally bottom right is all three rows of split halves if black bars. They're symbolic thoughh I forget what they symbolize (shame on me I was born in South Korean)

Comment: @North The angles and lengths might be a bit off too.  When I drew these, I intended them to be abstractions, and in that spirit, I didn't think it would be that important to represent everything perfectly.  Considering how unique that feature is and its symbolic significance, I should have probably just drawn the bars accurately.  I just uploaded a corrected image.

Comment: Nice job on the drawing btw (and thanks for changing the flag stripes) +1 (like a long time ago)

Comment: @paramesis how close is my partial answer? Right direction!

Comment: @North very interesting, but not quite.  There is something important about overlaying (as there always is when I use vellum).  The answers to the previous three puzzles would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is helpful for somebody.

> I noticed that maybe that I could layer all the vellums together. This is the result:[image]

Some notes:

> The empty is 1, filled circle/arrow is 2, the lines are 3, the stars are 4, and shaded parts are five. If some stuff over, half of the time the overlayered imaged will be next to each other. 
>
>  The numbers correspond to the whatever object fills that square. Numbers closer to the maze thingy is more in towards the actual maze thingy and farther away are farther away from the grid maze.